# Which words to use when adding another people to the "To" list of the email conversation

Tags: email

I would have tried "Added Angela and Peter to the conversation", but that does not refer the the fact that this conversation is over the email, and "Added Angela and Peter to the loop", but that would be only appropriate in a informal/corporate email types.

Is there a more standard way and preferably shorter way to express the fact of adding other people to the email recipient list?

Comment: You can use ++(name) to add a person into the conversation

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is writing advice, not a question about English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most emails where I add a name to the list of recipients, I let the “CC:” line among the addressees stand for that fact, and don't mention it specially.  If I were to mention it, and wanted to do so briefly and unobtrusively, I'd add a line like “Added CC: Angela, Peter” at the beginning or end.  More often, when I add a name to the list, it is for a particular reason, and I will address a paragraph or sentence to that person (eg: “Angela, please note XYZ”).  In that case it is redundant to say names have been added.

Answer (score 2):

My preference is simply:

> +Angela, Peter
>
> Sally, thanks for sending over the TPS reports...

Some email clients (e.g. Google Inbox) will actually recognize this format and add the relevant people to the conversation from your address book.

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding someone to an e-mail conversation and that person is known by all others on the e-mail, then it is most likely understood why that person is added. However, if you are adding someone who is not known to all recipients but is a decision maker or someone you would like to contribute to the conversation, you should clearly point that out at the top of the message. For example: "Added Angela Brown, our Manager to comment on this subject."

Answer (score 0):

You can simply say "Added Angela and Peter to recipient list" but as @jwpat7 said, the list of the recipients is normally visible to everybody who receives the email.

It be could useful to list those who receive the email when the recipient list shows just the email addresses, and you want to be sure the others know exactly who is receiving the email.  Suppose that the email address is apaderno@gmail.com; somebody could think that is the email address of Adele Paderno, when that is the email address used by Alberto Paderno. If you need to make that clear, you could add a line like the one I shown.